# How to locate current page and change the css in wordpress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have tried the code bellow, but its not working...
Im using the code bellow in a another project and its working, but when Im using the code in wordpress its not workig...

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var pathname = location.href;

    if (pathname === "http://wwww.findx.se/?page_id=10") {
        $('.xoxo').css({
            display: 'none'
        });
        $('div#footer').css({
            display: 'none'
        });
    }
    if (pathname === "http://www.findx.se/?page_id=9") {
        $('.xoxo').css({
            display: 'none'
        });
        $('div#footer').css({
            display: 'none'
        });
    }
    if (pathname === "http://www.findx.se/?page_id=8") {
        $('.xoxo').css({
            display: 'none'
        });
        $('div#footer').css({
            display: 'none'
        });
        $('#header').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Any error in console ?

Comment: @Brewal Thanks, I found some file path error...

Comment: Call your own jQuery JavaScript file, AFTER the wp_head function (<?php wp_head(); ?>) located in the header.php file (Wordpress).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Wordpress, then this might be the solution:

```
jQuery(function (jQuery) {
    var pathname = location.href;

    if (pathname === "http://wwww.findx.se/?page_id=10") {
        jQuery('.xoxo').css({
            display: 'none'
        });
        jQuery('div#footer').css({
            display: 'none'
        });
    }
    if (pathname === "http://www.findx.se/?page_id=9") {
        jQuery('.xoxo').css({
            display: 'none'
        });
        jQuery('div#footer').css({
            display: 'none'
        });
    }
    if (pathname === "http://www.findx.se/?page_id=8") {
        jQuery('.xoxo').css({
            display: 'none'
        });
        jQuery('div#footer').css({
            display: 'none'
        });
        jQuery('#header').hide();
    }
});
```

I solved many `jQuery not defined` problems with this.

And beside that, `Wordpress` adds a class on the body tag. Just `Firebug` it and see which class it is in. Than you can style it the way you want. That is much easier actually.

Comment: Thanks Johan, but your code is not working... I think my problem is that i get jQuery is not defined...

Comment: Hi Bruno, actually, this should solve your problem. Can you confirm that you have a jQuery file loaded on your website? Via Google or the jQuery site?

Comment: Ok, I dont really understand, but I have a javascript file with your code above... How to confirm that I have jQuery file loaded? What do you mean?

Comment: Yes, but can you check in your page source if you have a jQuery file, different from this one, in your site? Can you make a screenshot from you page source or something?

Comment: Ok, I have this file If you mean between the header: <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: Alright. Is that it? Because that would not be enought. That's just a stylesheet. Do you have a `.js` file?

Comment: @Johann Sorry, yes I have this file: <script src="http://findx.se/wp-content/themes/vvt-blank-theme/js/page-check.js" type="text/javascript">, where Im now using your code...

Comment: Haha, I know that you have that one brother. But another .js file, different than this one? Don't you have that?

Comment: Ok, this one: <script src="http://findx.se/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.8.3" type="text/javascript">

Comment: Hmm alright, so we can confirm that you have a jQuery file included. This is weird man. The code I gave did work for me...

Comment: Yeah, Its really weird man, maybe somebody knows the right answer of my problem... Thanks anyway Johan

Comment: No problemo my brother. I hope you can find it indeed!

Comment: Call your own jQuery JavaScript file, AFTER the wp_head function (<?php wp_head(); ?>) located in the header.php file (Wordpress). Your code is working Johan...

Comment: Well nice to hear if it's working! Accept it and marked it as solved in that way!

Answer (score 1):

Generally WordPress will add a class to the body tag that will allow you to select by page. For example for your first rule you could do in your CSS

```
.page-id-10 .xoxo {
    display:none;
}
```

Check your body tag on the page you are wanting to change to find out what classes you can use. You could also use it in your jQuery selectory

Answer (score 0):

I use following in my `functions.php` to add the page slug/name in the body tag

```
function add_body_class( $classes )
{
    global $post;
    if ( isset( $post ) ) {
        $classes[] = $post->post_type . '-' . $post->post_name;
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'add_body_class' );
```

As a result I get following (I'm using pretty URL)

```
class="single single-post postid-1281 single-format-standard post-taste-javascript-php-part-2-php-5-4"
```

in this cas, `post-taste-javascript-php-part-2-php-5-4` is my page slug and `postid-1281` is id, so I can use

```
.post-taste-javascript-php-part-2-php-5-4 .xoxo {
    display:none;
}
```

Or I can use

```
.postid-1281 .xoxo{
    display:none;
}
```

So, I doubt (but not sure) that, it could be

```
.pageid-10 .xoxo {
    display:none;
}
```

Or, you can use the code snippet (given above) in `functions.php` and just change

```
$classes[] = $post->post_type . '-' . $post->post_name;
```

to (to add your page id)

```
$classes[] = $post->post_type . '-id' . $post->ID;
```

As a result, it will add something like  `page-id10` in your `body` tag and you can use

```
.page-id10 .xoxo {
    display:none;
}
```

Also, alternatively, you can use

```
var pathname = location.href;
var id = pathname.split('=');
if(id[1] == 10 ){
    $('.xoxo').css('display', 'none');
}
```

You can check the body tag of the given example [right here](http://heera.it/taste-javascript-php-part-2-php-5-4).

**Update :**

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    // ...
});
```

should be (Pass the `jQuery` as argument)

```
(function($) {
    // your code goes here and can use $
    $('.xoxo').css('display', 'none'); // '$' will work now
})( jQuery );
```

Also, make sure, `jQuery` is loaded, using `alert(typeof jQuery);`. if, it shows `undefined` then `jQuery` is not loaded, so load it. Check [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) for more.

Comment: Hmmmmmm, I dont really understand your code, but my problem now seems to be that I get this error: jQuery is not defined jQuery(function($)

Comment: Call your own jQuery JavaScript file, AFTER the wp_head function (<?php wp_head(); ?>) located in the header.php file (Wordpress).

Answer (score 0):

Call your own jQuery JavaScript file, AFTER the wp_head function () located in the header.php file (Wordpress).